# How to convert from recursive function to loop(for while etc) in DOM(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom

I got this code while searching, however, I would like it to convert from recursive function to loop using for or while etc.
This code is about selecting all childnodes of Body in DOM(Javascirpt) and print on console.

```
<script>
function traverse(target, callback){
    if(target.nodeType === 1){
        callback(target);
        var c = target.childNodes;
        for(var i=0; i<c.length; i++){
            /* recursive function here */
            traverse(c[i], callback);       
        }   
    }
}
traverse(document.querySelector('body'), function(elem){
    console.log(elem);
});
</script>
```

Could you give me some tips? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The main idea of having a recursion is, usually, the fact that you don't know the depth of it. So if you know how deep can go target.childNodes, you can use for instead, but it will be for(for(... The other thing, is for better readability you can use this.childNodes.forEach(callback);

Comment: For your goal here, `document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' ).forEach( console.log )` would do the trick as well.

Comment: @Animus Thanks for your great tips. Yeah, I don't know the depth of it, so recursion is the best option, right? I don't know the reason, but I don't like recursive function than for, while loop. I don't know the reason though :)

Comment: @somethinghere Cool. Nice approach. I'm learning vanilla JS, and I just would like to convert recursion to loop, but that's nice. Thanks!

Comment: The reason you _need_ recursion for something like this is, like Animus said, you don't know how deep this rabbit hole goes, so you need to be able to call the function for as long as there are deeper layers to explore. A `while` loop would not allow this, as going back _up_ the tree to the next element isn't exactly easy in such a situation.

Comment: You are welcome.
somethinghere gave a better advice I think. Which is selecting every element with particular selector, however, you should have a selector, or their collection for it.

Comment: One can only loop a pre-defined array. As you don't know anything about the hierarchy of the elements, you can't iterate over them with a loop

Comment: @Animus Thanks, bro! I've learned from you guys a lot. Have a good one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can query the target element for all its children and iterate over them

```
function traverse(target, callback)
{
   var nodes = target.getElementsByTagName('*');
   callback(target);
   for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
   {
      callback(nodes[i]);
   }

}
```